# how to send data to therequest body to the server using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

String Params_body = "{"mobileNumber":"9968599840"}";
String Params_head = "{"clientId":"C11","version":"v1","txnToken":"" + txnToken + ""}";

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your service using the `@Header` and `@Query` annotations to indicate the params.

This is just an example of how your service should look like:

```
public interface RetrofitService {

   @GET("/v1/your/endpoint")
   Call<YourResponse> networkCall(
        @Header("clientId") String clientId,
        @Header("version") String version,
        @Header("txnToken") String txnToken,
        @Query("mobileNumber") String mobileNumber);
}
```

Then you just need to call the endpoint method and pass as parameter the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Body annotation and pass all the parameter as below class.

```
class ClienInfo
{
 String clientId,
 String version,
 String txnToken,
 String mobileNumber);
}
```

Use like this:-

```
@GET("/v1/your/endpoint")
Call<YourResponse> networkCall(@Body ClienInfo clientInfo);
```